# how to access the current page id in vue js and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

i am working on a blog with laravel and vuejs and i have written the comment part as a vuecomponent and inserted that in show function of my post like this

```
 @section('content');
.
.
.

        <comment></comment>
@endsection
```

where above i show the single post and the comment section below it .now i want to access 2 things 1-the user id who enters the comment and the more important the id of the post which the user is currently seeing in my case for example its

```
http://localhost:8000/blog/8
```

that number 8 . as far as i cant use blade and php in vue component how should i access them in vue component .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a number of things you need to do.

First, if you aren't doing that already, you need send the value of the single post and the user from your controller. You can then access it in the blade file. This post might help

Next, you should pass the post_id and user_id as props to the component  like so:

`<comment post_id="{{$post->id}}" user_id="{{$user->id}}"></comment>`

Lastly, make sure you register the props in your 'comment' component:

`props: ['post_id', 'user_id']`

Comment: that was really time saver thanks it helped alot :)